# kdb/q: Increase visible rows in browser

Tags: webserver, port, kdb, q-lang

Hi I am running kdb and usually use the browser for basic viewing of the tables by running the kdb on a port: **\p xxx**
My questions is how can I increase the visible rows in the browser? Currently I believe there is a fixed number of rows that are visible.
I would like to be able to view more or less rows.
Is there a settings or a command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is all the info you need
http://code.kx.com/q/ref/cmdline/#-c-http-size

Comment: I have added this to the first two rows of the script :
`\p 8000
\c 20 2000`
 but dimensions still the same. I mean the `c\ xxxx xxx` works in the q console but it doesn't have the same effect in the browser.

Comment: That's terminal output you are modifying - http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/Cmdlinec. You need to use \C

Comment: Ugh! Capital `-C` did it. I was using the `-c`, oversight.
So the right way is: `q file.q -C 1000 2000` Thanks @Sean

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the other answer, kdb allows you to change to the console size in a session with [`\c`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/syscmds/#c-console-size) or via command line with the [`-c`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/cmdline/#-c-console-size) flag. The HTTP size is with an upper case C ([`\C`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/syscmds/#c-http-size) and [`-C`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/cmdline/#-c-http-size)).

The HTTP size has limits of 10 and 2000 for both height and width, so if you wished to set a height of 2000 and width of 1000:

```
q)\C 2000 1000
```